# 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for allPosts in allPost1 and allPost2 and allPost3 and allPost4

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have so many keys in params and I want to display it on the template then I got an error that
`for` statements should use the format `for x in y`: `for allPosts in allPost1 and allPost2 and allPost3 and allPost4`

```html
<!--My html template-->
{% for allPosts in allPost1 and allPost2 and allPost3 and allPost4 %}
....
{% endfor %}

<!--My views template-->
def search1(request):
  ....
  params = {'allPost1': allpost1,'allPost2': allpost2,'allPost3': allpost3,'allPost4': allpost4, 'query': query}
      return render(request, "home/search1.html", params)
```

Comment: You can't use `and` to chain your "allPostx" lists/querysets, you could chain the `|add` filter instead https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#add. Can you share more of your view, do you need to be creating 4 different lists of posts or could you combine them into one in your view?

Answer (score 0):

You should chain the iterables in your *view*. A *view* implements the *business logic*, a *template* only the *rendering* logic.

We thus can implement this with:

```
from itertools import chain

def search1(request):
    # …
    context = {
        'allPost1': allpost1,
        'allPost2': allpost2,
        'allPost3': allpost3,
        'allPost4': allpost4,
        'allPosts': chain(allpost1, allpost2, allpost3, allpost4)
        'query': query
    }
    return render(request, 'home/search1.html', context)
```

then we render this with:

```
{% for post in allPosts %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

It is also rather odd that you have four iterables in the view. Usually you can "merge" the iterables to retrieve the posts with a *single* query.